Html rendered inside iframe is rendered different from html file
This is how the iframe sits on my Vue application:
<iframe
    srcdoc="plot.html"
    width="100%"
    height="1200"
    frameborder="0"
/>

Here is how it renders:

You can see that it fills the page both height and widht wise, however there are gaps on the left and right of the plot, as opposed to the raw html file, which renders like this:

Which is exactly what I need.
Does anyone have any idea on how I can do it?

This is unlikely related to vue as this would be the same problem with static layout. You need to narrow this down before limiting the question to vue

I think you need to just give the iframe more height. It looks like the images are adapting to the low height. Also, if the contents of the iframe come from another domain, you won't be able to directly change the style of the iframe content.

I have tried a lot of values in the Vue app, both in px (as it is currently) and with %, but no matter what the plot does not fill out.
The contents of the iframe are the html file from the second screenshot.

The srcdoc comes from your own app. You could style it directly so it takes up all the width and height of it's parent component. Is the graph dynamically generated or is it just an image?

The srcdoc is generated by plotly. Unfortunately I have no control over how it is styled.
